# An Error Occur when trying to query from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

could you guys help me please, i dont know what this error mean.
i got these error when trying to query to mongodb

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
property 'topology' closes the circle

Comment: Please share the code in question